# How do I make arrays dynamically with unique names without using a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I'm doing a challenge in which I'm forced to make new arrays to represent a random amount of rows. Part of the challenge forces the use of arrays and bans the use of a 2d array. Any help is appreciated.

Essentially it should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumber; i++) {
  String[] array + i = new String[10];
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `String[] array = new String[10];`?

Comment: As @Unmitigated pointed, you should try do all you need with one 1d array and then reallocate the same array to process new data. Other approach is use, for example, a linked of arrays or a hashmap of arrays, but I'm guessing this should also be against the rules of the challenge you are in. Other approach is to use one big 1d array and treat it as multiples arrays (example, index 0 to 9 is the first subarray, index 10 to 19 is the next, and so on).